# Windows Update fails with 8E5E03FE on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Two updates continually fail with error code 8E5E03FE;  Downloading the files and installing them directly don't make any difference.

The WindowsUpdate log says:

```
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr    *************
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr    ** START **  DnldMgr: Downloading updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdatesWuApp]
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr    *********
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr      * Call ID = {619FE112-A4F7-4F16-949D-D5F9864E7B21}
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr      * Priority = 3, Interactive = 1, Owner is system = 1, Explicit proxy = 0, Proxy session id = 1, ServiceId = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr      * Updates to download = 1
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    Agent      *   Title = Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows 7 (KB2360131)
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    Agent      *   UpdateId = {5F433AC8-D5E4-434D-9FE2-DE093BD71661}.103
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    Agent      *     Bundles 1 updates:
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    Agent      *       {56745877-75B3-4B52-85F5-6648928A5FF6}.103
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr    ***********  DnldMgr: New download job [UpdateId = {56745877-75B3-4B52-85F5-6648928A5FF6}.103]  ***********
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr      * Queueing update for download handler request generation.
2010-10-12    11:22:04:256    1072    284    DnldMgr    Generating download request for update {56745877-75B3-4B52-85F5-6648928A5FF6}.103
2010-10-12    11:22:04:757    1072    c70    AU    >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Download update [UpdateId = {7A2E9485-137C-420E-B5AF-16036AE20EB9}]
2010-10-12    11:22:04:757    1072    c70    AU      # WARNING: Download failed, error = 0x8E5E03FE
2010-10-12    11:22:04:757    1072    c70    AU    Setting AU scheduled install time to 2010-10-13 10:00:00
2010-10-12    11:22:04:757    1072    c70    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:04:757    1072    c70    AU    Currently showing Progress UX client - so not launching any other client
2010-10-12    11:22:04:767    1072    c70    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:04:897    1072    284    Handler    Generating request for CBS update 56745877-75B3-4B52-85F5-6648928A5FF6 in sandbox C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\0ba8bbf170120e90fad9d6f10a732014
2010-10-12    11:22:04:897    1072    284    Handler    Selected payload type is ptExpress
2010-10-12    11:22:04:897    1072    284    Handler    UH: DpxRestoreJob returned 0x80070002
2010-10-12    11:22:04:897    1072    284    Handler    Detected download state is dsHavePackage
2010-10-12    11:22:15:903    1072    fcc    Handler    FATAL: CBS called Error with 0x8e5e03fe, 
2010-10-12    11:22:15:903    1072    284    Handler    FATAL: UH: 0x8e5e03fe: Async stage operation failed in CUHCbsHandler::StageCbsPackage
2010-10-12    11:22:15:913    1072    284    Handler    FATAL: Request generation for CBS update complete with hr=0x8e5e03fe and pfResetSandbox=0 
2010-10-12    11:22:15:913    1072    284    Handler    FATAL: Error source is 106.
2010-10-12    11:22:15:913    1072    284    DnldMgr    FATAL: DM:CAgentDownloadManager::GenerateAllDownloadRequests: GenerateDownloadRequest failed with 0x8e5e03fe.
2010-10-12    11:22:15:913    1072    284    DnldMgr    Error 0x8e5e03fe occurred while downloading update; notifying dependent calls.
2010-10-12    11:22:15:963    1072    284    Agent    *********
2010-10-12    11:22:15:963    1072    284    Agent    **  END  **  Agent: Downloading updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdatesWuApp]
2010-10-12    11:22:15:963    1072    284    Agent    *************
2010-10-12    11:22:15:963    1072    284    Report    CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    284    Report    REPORT EVENT: {15F7FF36-61D8-433E-BF05-6435512D8907}    2010-10-12 11:22:04:056-0700    1    161    106    {7A2E9485-137C-420E-B5AF-16036AE20EB9}    100    8e5e03fe    AutomaticUpdatesWuApp    Failure    Content Download    Error: Download failed.
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Download update [UpdateId = {5F433AC8-D5E4-434D-9FE2-DE093BD71661}]
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU      # WARNING: Download failed, error = 0x8E5E03FE
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    #########
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    ##  END  ##  AU: Download updates
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    #############
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    Setting AU scheduled install time to 2010-10-13 10:00:00
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:15:973    1072    c70    AU    Currently showing Progress UX client - so not launching any other client
2010-10-12    11:22:15:983    1072    c70    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:16:023    1072    284    Report    CWERReporter::HandleEvents - WER report upload completed with status 0x8
2010-10-12    11:22:16:023    1072    284    Report    WER Report sent: 7.3.7600.16385 0x8e5e03fe 7A2E9485-137C-420E-B5AF-16036AE20EB9 Download 106 Unmanaged
2010-10-12    11:22:16:023    1072    284    Report    CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2010-10-12    11:22:16:083    1072    fcc    AU    Getting featured update notifications.  fIncludeDismissed = true
2010-10-12    11:22:16:083    1072    fcc    AU    No featured updates available.
2010-10-12    11:22:16:834    1072    fcc    AU    BeginInteractiveInstall invoked for Install
2010-10-12    11:22:16:834    1072    fcc    AU    Auto-approved 0 update(s) for install (for Ux), installType=0
2010-10-12    11:22:16:834    1072    fcc    AU    WARNING: BeginInteractiveInstall failed, error = 0x8024000C
2010-10-12    11:22:16:854    1072    ac4    AU    AU received handle event
2010-10-12    11:22:16:854    1072    ac4    AU    No featured updates notifications to show
2010-10-12    11:22:16:854    1072    ac4    AU    UpdateDownloadProperties: 0 download(s) are still in progress.
2010-10-12    11:22:16:854    1072    ac4    AU    Triggering Offline detection (non-interactive)
2010-10-12    11:22:16:854    1072    ac4    AU    AU setting pending client directive to 'Install Complete Ux'
2010-10-12    11:22:16:854    1072    ac4    AU    WARNING: Pending directive, 'Install Complete Ux', is not applicable
2010-10-12    11:22:16:874    1072    ac4    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:16:874    1072    ac4    AU    #############
2010-10-12    11:22:16:874    1072    ac4    AU    ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2010-10-12    11:22:16:874    1072    ac4    AU    #########
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    ac4    AU    <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {4E13F242-5B3D-45D9-A85C-7A5E5A294C81}]
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent    *************
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent    ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent    *********
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent      * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent      * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent      * ServiceID = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} Third party service
2010-10-12    11:22:16:884    1072    284    Agent      * Search Scope = {Machine}
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent    Update {AEB8AF4D-539A-4E28-97A8-359E093ED07D}.100 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent      * Added update {7A2E9485-137C-420E-B5AF-16036AE20EB9}.100 to search result
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent      * Added update {5F433AC8-D5E4-434D-9FE2-DE093BD71661}.103 to search result
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent      * Found 2 updates and 64 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 713 out of 1193 deployed entities
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent    *********
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent    **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2010-10-12    11:22:20:950    1072    284    Agent    *************
2010-10-12    11:22:20:960    1072    284    Report    REPORT EVENT: {F43227A7-E838-453B-A41D-F7CB97D153E9}    2010-10-12 11:22:15:923-0700    1    161    106    {5F433AC8-D5E4-434D-9FE2-DE093BD71661}    103    8e5e03fe    AutomaticUpdatesWuApp    Failure    Content Download    Error: Download failed.
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {4E13F242-5B3D-45D9-A85C-7A5E5A294C81}]
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU      # 2 updates detected
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    #########
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {4E13F242-5B3D-45D9-A85C-7A5E5A294C81}]
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    #############
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    No featured updates notifications to show
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    Setting AU scheduled install time to 2010-10-13 10:00:00
2010-10-12    11:22:20:970    1072    c70    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:21:060    1072    284    Report    CWERReporter::HandleEvents - WER report upload completed with status 0x8
2010-10-12    11:22:21:060    1072    284    Report    WER Report sent: 7.3.7600.16385 0x8e5e03fe 5F433AC8-D5E4-434D-9FE2-DE093BD71661 Download 106 Unmanaged
2010-10-12    11:22:21:060    1072    284    Report    CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2010-10-12    11:22:21:080    1072    c70    AU    Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2010-10-12    11:22:21:130    1072    888    AU    Getting featured update notifications.  fIncludeDismissed = true
2010-10-12    11:22:21:130    1072    888    AU    No featured updates available.
2010-10-12    11:22:25:977    1072    284    Report    CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursory look at your log reveals this as the salient line:

`# WARNING: Download failed, error = 0x8E5E03FE`

This appears to be a reference to the *download* failing, before the installation is even attempted.

Questions:

1. What is the KBxxxxxx number of the update that is failing?
2. Is this a particularly large or unusual update (e.g. a service pack)?
3. Given that the download is failing, I'm surprised by your comment that "downloading the files and installing them directly doesn't make a difference." Could you elaborate?

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Search the Microsoft Knowledge base for the KBxxxxxx number of the first update that is failing.
2. Download that update. (If you cannot download it at all from this computer, you have identified a network/firewall/connectivity issue. Can you download it from a different computer on this network? From a coffee shop?)
3. Install the update manually by running it while logged in as an administrator.
4. Report any specific error messages that result by commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might shed some light on your issue:  [Technet thread - error code 80070002](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistasp/thread/1dd9856b-1fd8-46d9-89ef-39b610e8cf18)

Since you didn't post any troubleshooting... try the gamut!  Off the top of my head, start with checking to see if it's blocked by hw or sw firewall.  Turn off UAC while updating.  Connect as direct to the internet as possible (bypass switches and routers as much as you can.)  Is your network connection steady, any 'noise on the line'?  Do you have probably with sustained file transfers?  Dump the cache for windows update, it may have corrupt files.  If possible, system restore to the day before the update error started.  Try running system file checker, it may turn up an error.  Run a disk defrag and a Ram & Hard disk checking utility.  Did this begin with internal WSUS or SCCM?  Check the source if internal... could be there.

Those things should get you well on your way to solving this issue.